# Javascript append form with multiples files

Tags: javascript, php, drag-and-drop

I try to append my form with multiples file from drag and drop action. I would like to submit form to the same php file. When the form is send, $_Post and $_files variables with appends are always empty. There is just parameters from original form. Any ideas ?

Index.php :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>HTML5 File Drag &amp; Drop API</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
<table>
<?php 
    var_dump($_POST);
    var_dump($_FILES);
}
?>
</table>
    <form action="index.php" id="upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <fieldset>
    <legend>Form</legend>

    <div>
        <label for="fileselect">Files to upload:</label>
        <input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple" />
        <div id="filedrag">or drop files here</div>
    </div>

    </fieldset>

    </form>

    <button id="submitbutton" >Upload Files</button>    

    <div id="messages">
    <p>Status Messages</p>
    </div>

<script src="filedrag.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

reduce of filedrag.js :

```
    function $id(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }

    // file selection
    function FileSelectHandler(e) {

        // cancel event and hover styling
        FileDragHover(e);

        // fetch FileList object
        var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;

        // process all File objects
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            myfiles.push(f);
            ParseFile(f);
        }

    }

    $id("submitbutton").onclick = function(){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        formData = new FormData(document.querySelector('form'));
        xhr.open('get','index.php');
        myfiles.forEach(file=>{
            formData.append("files[]", file);
        });
        formData.append("test", "test");
        xhr.send(formData);
    }
```

Comment: You aren't preventing the default form submit process. When page reloads that is not due to the ajax request, the only data sent is in the form itself. You also aren't trying to do anything with the ajax response

Comment: So it's not possible to append my form and call again the same page ?

Comment: Depends on what your expectations are here.

Comment: Ideally you should send the data using POST ajax request and prevent the submit action from executing the default handler. If the AJAX was successful you can then redirect the user to whichever page you want.

Comment: I want to have information of drag and drop files. Files add with the input dialogbox are in a readonly filelist variable and sent to index.php post variable but not drag and drop files. That's why I try to add it with append. So do you have a solution for me to get these files ?